# How to remove git commit default template message?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-config

If I want to create a custom *git commit template*, I can add path to template as:

```
[commit]
    template = ~/.gitmessage
```

But it keeps appending at the bottom of my commit template default template:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
# modified:   lib/test.rb
#
```

Reading on [configuration](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) they also have appended default template. I know it's commented out, but anyway to remove it so it only displays my custom template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `commit.status` to `false`.

```
git config commit.status false
```

or

```
git -c commit.status=false commit
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Can you just tell me what is `commit.status` ? Can't find it in refrence material.

Comment: @DinkoPehar It's a predefined config parameter. See more on https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config. When you have a requirement, you could search the documents first, where you may find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the default template with a git hook!

By default you'll have this git hook called `prepare-commit-msg.sample` which gives you a bit of an idea about what is possible. You can activate it by renaming the file:

```
 cp .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg
```

Now if you commit, the 'default template' is gone. Please note that git hooks are stored in your `.git/hooks` directory but you can't push these to a remote easily. There is lots of info in the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) on this topic.